# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Springboot 2.5.8

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to practice a spring boot microservice application. I want to remove it from the postgresql container on docker. But I am getting an error when starting the project.

Error:

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.8)

2023-05-19 19:03:52.670  INFO 20084 --- [           main] c.m.s.p.ProductServiceApplication        : Starting ProductServiceApplication using Java 17.0.7 on goktug with PID 20084 (D:\product-service\target\classes started by GOKTUG in D:\product-service)
2023-05-19 19:03:52.673  INFO 20084 --- [           main] c.m.s.p.ProductServiceApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-05-19 19:03:53.923  INFO 20084 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-19 19:03:54.032  INFO 20084 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 90 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-19 19:03:55.109  INFO 20084 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-05-19 19:03:55.121  INFO 20084 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-19 19:03:55.121  INFO 20084 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2023-05-19 19:03:55.259  INFO 20084 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-19 19:03:55.259  INFO 20084 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2507 ms
2023-05-19 19:03:55.345  WARN 20084 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-05-19 19:03:55.349  INFO 20084 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-05-19 19:03:55.368  INFO 20084 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-19 19:03:55.389 ERROR 20084 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
      4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.8</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.mycompany.stockmanagement</groupId>
<artifactId>product-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>product-service</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--swagger-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
spring:
application:
  name: product-service
 config:
  activate:
  on-profile: localhost
main:
 allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
info:
component: Product Service

  server:
    port: 9788

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
     on-profile: localhost
  cloud:
   config:
    uri: http://localhost:8888
  jpa:
   hibernate:
     ddl-auto: update
     database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
       default_schema: stock_management
  datasource:
   url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/stock_management"
    username: admin
   password: admin
```

Comment: "*`Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class`*" - Looks like the `driverClassName` is missing. See [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/turing85/quarkus-vs-spring/blob/HEAD/spring/src/main/resources/application.yml#L6) for an example.

Comment: @Turing85 I added the place you said but it still keeps giving the same error.

Comment: @Turing85 I want to connect 5556:5432 container named eloquent_wing via Docker. Is that why I'm getting an error?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing how you started the container.